# Is the Relocation register changed in terms of memory mapping and allocation?

Tags: memory, operating-system, theory

I was just reading through a Operating Systems book, and it makes reference to the relocation register in the conversion of logical addresses to physical addresses.

I understand how they're converted. Essentially the logical address is added to the relocation register to get the physical memory address. (Very simplistic version).

But for this to work, the relocation register would have to be constantly changing if there was more than one process.

For example if the relocation register was a constant 2000, processes would constantly be given the same physical memory address.

So How exactly if the value of the relocation register found? 
and how is it changed?

Thanks for all the help! The book kind shy's away from this.

Comment: In general, when you switch between processes, you have to restore _every_ register value. I wouldn't like my register R7 to suddenly hold a completely new value just because the OS swapped to another program which used R7 for its purposes. Now Windows 3.x did have some subtly different rules, but that was because it swapped between processes only when a syscall was made, and those changed registers anyway.

Comment: Those register values are changed as part of context switching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logical address of a memory allocated to a process is the combination of base register and limit register.
When this logical address is added to the relocation register, it gives the physical address.
[image: Logical memory -> Physical memory conversion]

So even when the Relocation register is constant, the process would be given a different physical address since the processes' logical address would change.

**How exactly is the value of the relocation register found?**

The value of relocation register will be set by the OS and no user process can access this value. Only the Memory Management Unit knows this value.

**How is it changed?**

The value can be changed by the Operating System.

---

Side Note: The whole point of having relocation registers is to avoid user processes accessing physical addresses. The OS resides in physical memory with a address range of 0-Relocation Register.

Comment: @user1005284,so cpu generates different logical address for each process?

Answer (score 3):

This register is set to the desired value (so-called *base address*) by the OS, just before executing each program.

In a multitasking environment, the OS not only launches programs, but also regularly *switches contexts* between all of them, to give the illusion of simultaneous execution. A context switch from process A to process B thus now includes the following operations:

- stop execution of process A,
- save contents of CPU into A's PCB (Process Control Block),
- save contents of relocation register into A's PCB (i.e. save A's *base address* into PCB),
- update relocation register with B's base address (found in B's PCB),
- load contents of CPU from B's BCP. Because this includes the PC register, the CPU resumes executing B right away.